# FireBird SQL: skip one of the returning parameters

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, triggers, firebird

I have a FireBird SP that returns 3 output parameters to modify 3 fields
Then I call this sp with before update or insert trigger

I want now to check for a condition column value inside the SP if it is = 1 then the second output parameter must be left as it is with the user data and prevent the sp to change it

How I do that ?

The trigger:

```
execute procedure my_proc inp1, inp2 RETURNING_VALUES op1, op2, op3;
```

I don't want to return op2 and leave it as it is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to add third input parameter which takes the current value of the `op2` and returns it in case of "condition column value = 1". IOW you add an "default value for the `op2`" input parameter.